# Angular 6 SSR with ASP .Net Core 2.1: window not defined

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using Asp .net core 2.1 with angular 6.0.2 server side rendering. But my issue is that When ever i add Routing to my angular app it gives me error "window not defined" while rendering the page on server side.
I have tried adding an empty component with routing and gives me the same error.
while using the app without routing works perfectly with SSR.
I am not able to figure out why this is happening?
Error stack is :

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: 'window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at factory (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\common\bundles\common.umd.js:5610:169)
    at _callFactory (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8457:24)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8415:30)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8390:21)
    at _callFactory (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8463:71)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8415:30)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8375:25)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9083:20)
    at RouterInitializer.bootstrapListener (C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\router\bundles\router.umd.js:5354:48)
    at C:\Users\asd\Desktop\YJewellery\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:4677:60'
```

Comment: `https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830` try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // put your browser code here
}
```

Because Window object is not defined on the server. It is the Browser Object